# getting rid of redundant type parameters

Tags: c#

I have a generic class A, and another class B that handles instances of A and contains some additional data. I need to have two separate classes. B can't inherit from A, because A has other derivatives, B needs to contain a reference to an A.

As a simple example, what I would like to write is this (dictionary is A, dicthandler is B):

```
class dicthandler<T> where T : Dictionary<Tk, Tv>
```

But it doesn't compile, I need to specify all type parameters:

```
class dicthandler<T, Tk, Tv> where T : Dictionary<Tk, Tv>
```

But I actually don't care what Tk and Tv is, so they are completely redundant, I just need T. Whenever I want to create a new instance, I need to specify all type parameters for the constructor, which hurts me.

So clearly I need some tricks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there's no way of doing this. Any instance of `DictHandler` *must* know the exact type of `T`, including the type of `TKey` and `TValue`.

You can use type inference to reduce how often you need to explicitly specify type arguments though, if you actually *have* an instance of the relevant dictionary. For example:

```
public static class DictHandler
{
    public static DictHandler<T, TKey, TValue> CreateHandler<T, TKey, TValue>
        (T dictionary1, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary2)
        where T : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
    {
        return new DictHandler<T, TKey, TValue>();
    }
}

public class DictHandler<T, TKey, TValue> where T : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
}
```

Then create it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
var handler = DictHandler.CreateHandler(dict, dict);
```

I believe the reason you have to have the two parameters is so that the arguments (which are all that gets used in type inference) end up corresponding with parameters which *directly* mention the type parameters. I'm not entirely sure though - and this is certainly somewhat ugly.

Another alternative is to create a base type or base interface for A which *isn't* generic. For example, in this case (assuming we could control Dictionary) we'd create:

```
public interface INonGenericDictionary
{
    // Members which don't rely on the type parameters
}

public class Dictionary<TKey, TValue> : INonGenericDictionary
{
    ...
}
```

then

```
public class DictHandler<T> where T : INonGenericDictionary
{
    ...
}
```

We can't really tell whether that's suitable in your case, but it *may* be.

Comment: The extension method is a good idea, but sadly, it doesn't work. See http://pastebin.com/bxDvDgrT , "... cannot be inferred ..."

Comment: @fejesjoco: It's not an extension method - just a static method. But yes, I see what you mean. Hmm... seeing what I can do...

Comment: @fejesjoco: Okay, I've got it working with a bit of a grotty hack. It's far from ideal though - if you can get the second approach to work, that would be better.

Comment: I thought about non-generics. But some methods of the handler would need an other dictionary as a parameter (for example, comparing or merging). In this case, there would be no compile-time restriction on what actual dictionaries you could pass to it, like you can't give <int,string> to a <string,object> handler, I would need run-time checks.

Comment: @fejesjoco: If they're going to use another dictionary, then you *do* need to know the type parameters, to make sure that parameter has the same compile-time type then. Your original claim that you don't care about `Tk` and `Tv` is incorrect. They may be arbitrary types, but you clearly need to be able to refer to them elsewhere.

Comment: I meant another instance but of the same type. So I don't need to refer to Tk and Tv, I need to refer to T.

Comment: I guess it's not possible then. You get the checkmark for the effort, the others get a +1.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to object construction, current C# demands that you be very specific. This seems like an unlikely thing to create very often, though, so you could just create a `CreateDictHandler` type from the current type's type-parameters:

```
private dicthandler<T, Tk, Tv> CreateDictHandler() {...}
...
var handler = CreateDictHandler();
```

If the type-parameters are for the *method* you'll have to supply them for the constructor, but you can still use `var` on the variable declaration.

---

You *may* also find that in many cases *too much* generics is actually a bad thing. If it starts to get too gnarly, there are times when things like `IDictionary` (non-generic) are genuinely desirable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot omit the key and value type arguments since they are part of the generic type signature.  But have you considered changing your type definition to this?

```
class dicthandler<TKey, TValue>
```

Then you can just use the type `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.  It's apparent that your type will be used only with dictionaries, so there should be no need to force this type to be passed as a generic argument since you already know what it is.

Comment: This wouldn't work because A can have derivatives, I don't know if it's a Dictionary or something else that derives from it.

Comment: @fejesjoco: Then use `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`?  Or is the specific type somehow important to your class?